# SSIS package attempts to run with wrong version of c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I've made a SSIS package for SQL Server 2017 (version 14.0.3238.1 specifically) involving a c# script task, however when I attempt to run it produces a "Cannot load script for execution" error which suggests its trying to use the wrong version of C#. This is confirmed when I dig around a bit and find the server attempts to execute the script in Microsoft Visual C# 2015 not the 2017 that visual studio demands you use.

As far as I know you SQL Server 2017 would be using Microsoft Visual C# 2017, so do I need to update something or was the server incorrectly configured when it was set up?

Comment: What is the connection string?  The connection string may be pointed to the wrong server.

Comment: I have nothing more to add except to say that script tasks are nothing but trouble. I have not come across a single instance where they weren't a massive annoyance to maintain. Don't try to upgrade them either! We have nearly the same issue as you. Good luck!

Comment: @jdweng, no that not the problem, the script task is doing stuff on the server itself, moving stuff around and opening up zip files to ready data to be loaded.

Comment: I think the default is Version 4.0, you can change the version of .NET on the Solution properties. Right click in solution explorer and select properties. There will be a drop down to choose the .NET version. However, you would know when you build it if there is a problem.

Comment: Is the csproj have correct version?  You do have SQL Server 2017 installed on the machine.  The script is checking the Program Files Folder for the executable and a different folder is used for each version of the server.  I would search for SQLCMD.EXE in program folder and see if it can be found.  It is a command line utility that comes with SQL Server and will indicate if the the utilities have been installed.  There use to be two download of the SQL Server.  I partial version and a full version.  Maybe only the partial was installed.

Comment: What version of windows are you running on the server? We had this same problem on a windows 2012 server and had to roll back the Script Language in the script task to use C# 2012.